# HABTM link tables not taking isolate_namespace value in mountable engine

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-engines

I am currently developing a mountable engine. Within the engine I have the following two models:

```
  module Ems
    class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
    end
  end

  module Ems
    class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :channels
    end
  end
```

These are the db migration files:

```
  class CreateEmsChannels < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :ems_channels do |t|
        t.string :slug
        t.string :name

        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end

  class CreateEmsCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :ems_categories do |t|
        t.string :slug
        t.string :name
        t.text :strapline

        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end


  class CreateEmsCategoriesChannels < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
      # Create the association table
      create_table :ems_categories_channels, :id => false do |t|
        t.integer :category_id, :null => false
        t.integer :channel_id, :null => false
      end

      # Add table index
      add_index :ems_categories_channels, [:category_id, :channel_id], :unique => true
    end
  end
```

The problem starts when I try to retrieve the associated objects.
As an example, when I call `@channel.get :categories` I get the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'ems_development.categories_channels' doesn't exist: 
SELECT `ems_categories`.* 
FROM `ems_categories` 
INNER JOIN `categories_channels` 
ON `ems_categories`.`id` = `categories_channels`.`category_id` 
WHERE `categories_channels`.`channel_id` = 1
```

As you can see its missing off the isolate_namespace value on the link table, as it should look for the association on the table `ems_categories_channels` not `categories_channels`

Anyone had similar problems or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see, does your engine include `isolate_namespace` itself or not? 

    module Ems
      class Engine < Rails::Engine
        isolate_namespace Ems
      end
    end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can explicitly set the join table name ([per the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many-label-Options)).

```
  module Ems
    class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, :join_table => 'ems_categories_channels'
    end
  end

  module Ems
    class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :channels, :join_table => 'ems_categories_channels'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Yeah, I get that however I thought it should have picked this up automatically. Because Rails does so much in the background I don't want any misconfigurations as they might coma back to haunt me.  
Any ideas whether the join table should have to be set manually?

Comment: Usually, it uses the convention of the two tables names, alphabetically sorted, with any set model `table_prefix` and `table_suffix` wrapping the result ([as outlined in the source here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/has_and_belongs_to_many.rb#L42)).

It seems not to take into account `module` encapsulation for a join table like it is doing for the models.

It's not going to be a misconfiguration if you are explicitly setting it, which you either need to do using `:join_table` or potentially the model prefix/suffix attributes.